# What's the shortest way to plot points with opencv and c++?

Tags: c++, opencv

I couldn't find anything in highgui... Do I have to use Qt/GTK to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_drawing_functions.html?highlight=poly#polylines